# Sharing android project with eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, sharing

I am working on android game via Eclipse, and I am working with a designer that knows nothing of programming. Thus, he does not have any necessary tool (eclipse and the android plugin) to run our project in his phone. Is there someway for me to send him the application? This application is still in progress, so I can't publish it somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sign it as if you were going to release it to get the APK. After that, it's a matter of getting it on the phone.

1. He can download it from a server. Open the apk in the phone and it will install.
2. Email it to him. Gmail will even auto-install it if he has his Gmail on the phone.
3. He can put the apk in the file system manually. Set the phone up to be a Media Device, then simply put the APK on the phone like you would a thumb drive. Then he needs a file explorer like [Astro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.metago.astro&hl=en) to open the apk. It will then install.
4. Dropbox and other file syncing systems will auto-download the APK to the phone if you have a shared folder. This is nice for easy updates. He still need to manually install them.

For every case, he needs to set the phone to allow installs from "Unknown Sources" via the Security section in `Settings`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the fastest way for him to try it is sending him the .apk that can be found in YourProject/bin/youproject.apk.

That .apk is the one that eclipse uploads and runs in the device/emulator when you are running your app from eclipse.

Every time there is a change a new .apk will be generated which you should send for him to see those changes.

Answer (score 0):

Because you want to track your dev build, you should consider building it and then having your process upload your artifacts to Amazon S3 so you have a archive of all your builds released internally. Then just give him the link and he can download it and install it, this process will simplify the internal releasing of your APKs.